# MySql showing 800 connections when no user is online?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, mysql-workbench

I am using Springboot for Server side development and mysql workbench is showing more than 800 connection in development server when no user is connected or online. Here is the screenshot of mysql workbench server status.

[image: MySQL Workbench Screenshot]

Please help how am i getting these number of connection and how can I rectify this error.

Comment: Is it causing a problem? If not, what's the issue? If you have processes on standby waiting for connections they'll have idle connections at the ready.

Comment: Your framework is possibly using persistent connections. That shouldn't be an issue, as long as connections are effectively reused when needed.

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy a spring-boot application it creates a connection pool which sits idle if there is not load on the server (meaning in your terms that no user is online) these connections are still maintained. Hence, when you check the number of DB connections from WorkBench, it'll show you that many number of connections used by server.